# Is there a verb that means "repurpose a religious building for the needs of a different religious group"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

You know when buildings initially made for a particular religion is used by a group of a different religion? I am not sure if it happens in real life, but how would you say it? There must be a way to say it in a simple manner, but I can't think of a good way that sounds natural.

For example:

> This ancient abandoned Christian church was ___ a group of Hindus who
>   immigrated to the country recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This ancient abandoned Christian church was **converted by** a group of Hindus who immigrated to the country recently.

Similar to the [description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagia_Sophia) about Hagia Sophia in Istanbul:

> Nevertheless, the Christian cathedral made a strong impression on the new Ottoman rulers and they decided to **convert** it into a mosque.